# OneClass SVM classification for text data

Tags: python, classification

**Problem:**

I need to classify whether a document is checked or not checked. I have only text dataset for check document and if a document does not consist the check data it can automatically be classified as not checked.

I found that it can be doe using OneClass SVM. Below are the dataset and program implemented by me.

**Code:**

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
ps = PorterStemmer()

stop = stopwords.words('english')
data_test = pd.DataFrame({"Keywords":["Barge ID", "Check"]})
data = pd.DataFrame({"Keywords":["Vessel Name", "Barge ID", "Barge/Vessel", "VESSEL"]})

data['Keywords'] = data['Keywords'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
data['Keywords'] = data['Keywords'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ').replace('\s+',' ')

data_test['Keywords'] = data_test['Keywords'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
data_test['Keywords'] = data_test['Keywords'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ').replace('\s+',' ')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_features = 200, ngram_range = ( 1,3 ), sublinear_tf = True )
data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform( data['Keywords'] )

clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)
clf.fit(data_features)

test_data_features = vectorizer.transform(data_test['Keywords'])

print(clf.predict(test_data_features))
```

I tried it for a small sample code but then to it did not work. it is wrongly indicating as -1 for Barge ID and 1 for Check

Answer (score 1):

Train/test split is not done correctly in the code. Train/test split should be done with scikit-learn's [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function.

Comment: Did not perform train split here. Created a sample data for checking.